# Redefinition of the operator <<in a singleton

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, singleton, operator-overloading

I have a class in C++ on Linux that allows me to display messages on the console, depending on where the application is running. If it works in my computer, the messages displayed in console mode. Otherwise, everything is recorded in a text file for later viewing. And I created an extern object to use it. I wanted to try to make this class a singleton, but without success. I have this error appears to be when I come to compile my program:

> error: invalid operands of types 'Log *' and 'const char [12]' to binary 'operator <<'

And also:

> error: no match for 'operator <<' in 'logOutput' << Buffer_T ....

I would like your opinion. Thank you in advance for your attention.

My functional class currently

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer_T;

class Log
{
public:
    Log();
    virtual ~Log();

    void init()
    {
    #indef FriendlyArm
        output = new ofstream("/home/arm/Log.txt");
    #else
        output = &cout;
    #endif
    }


    template<typename T>
    Log operator<<( T const& value )
    {
        (*output) << value;
        return *this;
    }

    Log& operator<<( std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&) )
    {
        (*output) << f;
        return *this;
    }

    Log& operator<<(Buffer_T& Buf)
    {
        if( Buf.size() > 0 )
        {
            for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Buf.size(); i++ )
            {
                if( Buf[i] >= 32 && Buf[i] <= 127 )
                {
                    (*output) << Buf[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    (*output) << "0x" << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::hex << std::setw( 2 ) << unsigned( Buf[i] );
                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }


private:
    ostream *output;
};
#endif /* LOG_H_ */
```

And here is my attempt to singleton

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer_T;

class Log
{
    public:
        static Log *createOrGet()
        {
            if(_unique == NULL)
            {
                _unique = new Log();
            }

            return _unique;
        }

        static void kill()
        {
            if(_unique != NULL)
            {
                delete _unique;
                _unique = NULL;
            }
        }

        void init()
        {
        #indef FriendlyArm
            output = new ofstream("/home/arm/Log.txt");
        #else
            output = &cout;
        #endif
        }

        template<typename T>
        Log operator<<( T const& value )
        {
            (*output) << value;
            return *this;
        }

        Log& operator<<( std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&) )
        {
            (*output) << f;
            return *this;
        }

        Log& operator<<(Buffer_T& Buf)
        {
            if( Buf.size() > 0 )
            {
                for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Buf.size(); i++ )
                {
                    if( Buf[i] >= 32 && Buf[i] <= 127 )
                    {
                         (*output) << Buf[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (*output) << "0x" << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::hex << std::setw( 2 ) << unsigned( Buf[i] );
                    }
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        Log();
        virtual ~Log();
        static Log *_unique;
        ostream *output;
};
Log *Log::_unique = NULL;
#endif
```

Comment: @John They're not ideal most of the time but it's annoying to constantly have someone bug you about how much they hate them. Just so you know, singletons _can_ be useful; just check the implementation of some Boost libraries.

Comment: @Paul:  I wasn't talking to you.  OP may legitimately not be aware that Singletons are frequently a bad design technique.

Comment: @John You weren't talking to me?! What age are you?!

Comment: @Paul:  I'm simply trying to point out that I wasn't "bugging" *you*.  I was "bugging" the OP.

Comment: @Jean:  Please post test code that replicates this problem.

Comment: @John:  Log *logOutput;
 logOutput = Log::createOrGet();
 logOutput << "ProcessCommand called" << endl;
 logOutput << Data << endl;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: Don't take it the wrong way, but you make some mistakes that show you're not very experienced and singletons are very hard to use properly. In the case of a logger they are okay, just make sure to always use them as a last resort.

I don't have the time to go over why `operator<<` isn't working for you, but here's some tips on how to improve your singleton (you also seem to be asking for advice on that).

**The Instance function**

```
// The idiomatic way is to call this function 'Instance',
// but this doesn't really matter.
static Log& Instance() {
    static Log obj;
    return obj;
}
```

That's called Meyer's singleton. For single threaded application it's great: the instance gets created on the first call of the function and *automatically* gets destroyed when the application closes (you don't need a `kill` function).

**Your private virtual destructor**

I notice you have a private virtual destructor. You only need a virtual destructor when there's at least one other virtual function in the class. This is not the case; make the destructor non-virtual.

**Enforcing a single instance**

You made the constructor private — that's good, you are preventing me from directly creating multiple instances of the singleton. However you did not prevent me from making copies of the existing singleton. To also prevent that you also need to make the CopyConstructor and AssignmentOperator non-public:

```
protected:
  Log();
  Log(const Log&); // CopyConstructor
  Log& operator=(const Log&); // AssignmentOperator
  ~Log();
```

(The destructor should also be private in order to prevent me from deleting the only instance of the class.)

Also notice I made them `protected`, not `public`. If you don't know the difference, look it up (not enough space to explain here). I made them `protected` so you could inherit from the `Log` class if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

```
  Log *logOutput;
  logOutput = Log::createOrGet();
  logOutput << "ProcessCommand called" << endl;
  logOutput << Data << endl;
```

The problem: Your `Log::createOrGet()` returns a `Log*`, while the defined `operator<<` take a `Log` (note the lack of a '*' there).

There are two solutions:

- Use `*logOutput` everywhere. This is cumbersome, so it's better to use the alternative:
- Change the definition to `Log& logOutput;` and adjust `Log::createOrGet()` to return a `Log&` (for the last point: see Paul Manta's definition for `Instance()` )

Don't forget to read and understand Paul Manta's remarks as well!

**NOTE**: Although this will solve the quoted error message, this will not solve other problems in your code. Rewriting your code seems the only solution; see Paul Manta's answer (again) for suggestions.

Comment: There are more problems than just this.

Comment: @JohnDibling You might be right, I didn't test it in a compiler. IMHO, the code is too complex for whatever it tries to achieve (and that's why I redirected to Paul Manta's remarks). But at least my answer explains the quoted error message.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of your OP, you posted the following test harness:

```
int main()
{
    Log *logOutput; 
    logOutput = Log::createOrGet(); 
    logOutput << "ProcessCommand called";
    logOutput << Data << endl; // I dont know what Data is, so I commented this out
}
```

You need to dereference `logOutput` in order to stream to it.  Otherwise you are streaming to a pointer to the log, rather than to the log itself.

But you have other problems as well.  Your method template:

```
template<typename T>
Log operator<<( T const& value )
{
    (*output) << value;
    return *this;
}
```

returns a `Log` by value, which will result in a temporary that is destroyed when it goes out of scope, but `Log::~Log` is declared `private`, so is inaccessible.

Change your `operator<<`s to return a `Log` by reference:

```
template<typename T>
const Log& operator<<( T const& value ) const
{
    (*output) << value;
    return *this;
}

Log& operator<<( std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&) )
{
    (*output) << f;
    return *this;
}

Log& operator<<(Buffer_T& Buf) 
{
    if( Buf.size() > 0 )
    {
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < Buf.size(); i++ )
        {
            if( Buf[i] >= 32 && Buf[i] <= 127 )
            {
                    (*output) << Buf[i];
            }
            else
            {
                (*output) << "0x" << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::hex << std::setw( 2 ) << unsigned( Buf[i] );
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```